# error installing rails failed to build gem native extension for ruby 2.3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using ubuntu 20.04
I am trying to install rails with
`gem install rails -v 5.0.0.1`
I am using ruby 2.3.1 and rvm 1.29.12
but I am getting the following error:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    current directory: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ext/nokogiri
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -I /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0 -r ./siteconf20210808-45389-if7v5h.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.4.0
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Nokogiri depends on `libxml` library to be built. And to build native extensions you will need to |build-essential` package too.

You can install these packages by:

```
sudo apt install libxml2 build-essential
```

`build-essential` will install the necessary tools to compile native C libraries on your machine

`libxml2` is a library written in C to parse XML

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run this command to fix this error.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
```

And than install nokogiri gem

```
sudo gem install nokogiri
```